# ES6 object destructing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

In ES6, is `({width: this.width} = this.canvas);` the same as `this.width = this.canvas.width;`?

If not, what will the correct code be?

Comment: Both are valid in ES6 and have the same effect on `this`.